# Error Testing Sample Payment Form for SquareConnect

Tags: square-connect

I am trying to incorporate the SquareConnect [sample form](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form/) and [sample code](https://github.com/square/connect-python-sdk#documentation-for-api-endpoints) into my application. My application runs on GAE using Python 2.7 and Django 1.5. I have downloaded the repositories for squareconnect, certifi, dateutil, and urllib3. I have added the form into a django template and the form is loading correctly, and doing validations. In my views.py, I have the following at the top:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

import uuid
import squareconnect
from squareconnect.rest import ApiException
from squareconnect.apis.transaction_api import TransactionApi`

In the view function, I have the following:

```
api_instance = TransactionApi()
access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
location_id = 'YOUR_LOCATION_ID' 
nonce = 'YOUR_NONCE'
...
```

followed by the rest of the sample code.

However, when I run locally to test, I am getting the following error on `api_instance = TransactionApi()`:

`'module' object has no attribute 'CERT_REQUIRED'`

The error logs indicate it is line 101 of the rest.py file, which is the line:

`cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED`

Any help would be appreciated for how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like python around versions 2.7.8 and 2.7.9 has some issues around ssl. Notably, [this conversation](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/477) seems relevant. However, I'm not a python expert by any means. I'm on macOS with python 2.7.10 and cannot reproduce the error. The python SDK is built to support python 2.7.9 and above. It's also possible that the python instance you're using wasn't built with ssl.

- What exact version of python are you running?
- What OS are you on?
- Do you have openssl installed?
- Is this error on your local machine or on GAE instances?
- Does python have ssl support?

You can check python for ssl support via the following:

```
import socket
hasattr(socket, 'ssl')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was running Python 2.7.6, and upgraded to 2.7.9 (Django 1.5 doesn't seem to be compatible with 2.7.10). I am still getting the same error. OS = Windows 8. I do not have openssl installed. I tried deploying to GAE, and my website won't even load as it fails to load the Square models. Python does have SSL support; I ran your commands and they worked fine. At this point I think I will just use a different product than Square, have wasted so much time and not received any help from their support.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by no longer using the Square SDK. Instead I am using the [REST API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/). If others are trying to integrate Square with Django and/or GAE, this might be the way to go to avoid the issues that I have run into with the SDK.